# Compact multiple selectors using Stylus?

Tags: css-selectors, stylus

Given a mixed list of CSS selectors like below, is there anything I can do to make it more compact, other than removing commas and brackets? I am not asking for the absolutely smallest code, just whatever makes good sense when using Stylus.

```
.cl_nw,
.cl_n,
.cl_ne,
.selected .color_fg1,
.selected .color_fg2,
.selected .color_fg3,
.alert_nw,
.alert_n,
.alert_ne,
ul.checklists li.list_item span.tasks span.progress b,
.menuPopupList li.selected,
.menuPopupList li.selected a,
.menuPopupList li.selected a:visited,
.suggestionBox li.selected,
a.undo {
  background-color: #eb6d20;
}
```

Comment: Assign the color to a variable and use that variable instead of hardcoding the color directly into the style rule. That doesn't shorten your code, but it obviates the need to group all these otherwise unrelated selectors into a single style rule.

Comment: @BoltClock, I understand your point. I just want to confirm that I am not missing some more "advanced" Stylus usage; that there really is no way to apply Stylus-type nesting to this mix of selectors, without splitting it.

Comment: I'm not sure that there is. I think any more granular approaches would depend quite a bit on the markup this stylesheet was specifically designed for (for example, why does a background need to be assigned to both `.menuPopupList li.selected` and its `a` elements? Is it because links always come with their own backgrounds by default? Could that be simplified by assigning a transparent background to `.menuPopupList li.selected a, .menuPopupList li.selected a:visited` elements?).

Comment: Your suggestion makes sense, but this is not my code, so I don't want to rework it much. I'm customizing the appearance in the browser using [Stylus extension](https://github.com/openstyles/stylus), so I found (using "Inspect") the rule responsible for the current appearance and am just replacing the color.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not used to [stylus](/questions/tagged/stylus) pre-processing thing, but reading their documentation they have an exemple using multiple selectors on a variable and use with string interpolation:

```
selectorsList = '.cl_nw, .cl_n, .cl_ne, .selected .color_fg1 '

{selectorsList}
     color: red
```

That later compiles to this:

```
.cl_nw,
.cl_n,
.cl_ne,
.selected .color_fg1 {
    color: #000;
}
```

Important to note, that you **must** use commas in this approach or the compiler will assume that you are using a hierarchy selector

This of course will not fully compact your code with some *advanced* technic as you comment, but in my *personal* oppinion, can help the easy maintence of the code and the clear vision of waht is being applied to the selectors

[Try it online](http://stylus-lang.com/try.html#?code=mySelectors%20%3D%20'.cl_nw%2C%20.cl_n%2C%20.cl_ne%2C%20.selected%20.color_fg1'%0A%0A%7BmySelectors%7D%0A%20%20color%3A%20red)

See the full section documentation [here](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/interpolation.html)